# Add blur event to TinyMCE after initialisation with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor created using the TinyMCE jQuery plugin, initialised like

```
$('textarea').tinymce(mceOptions);
```

I want to add some behaviour to the blur event, and most solutions I've seen use something like

```
tinyMCE.dom.Event.add(tinyMCE.getInstanceById("editor-id").getWin(), "blur", function(){
   // Blur operations
});
```

inside the options.

I don't want to do this because the mceOptions are pulled from somewhere else, and this is all happening in the context of a backbone.js view. On the blur event I will be calling a method of the view, so I don't want to try to tell it to do that anywhere else than in the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(tinymce.get("editor-id").getBody()).bind(
   'blur',
   function(){
      /*do whatever you want here*/
   }
);
```